# How can i get a GraphQL Flutter app running that has the following error?

Tags: flutter, graphql

I followed [this](https://morioh.com/p/c905f39b3282) tutorial from the internet and tried to run a flutter graphql app. But when i try to run it i get the following error

C:\Users\Owner flutter run --debug
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G925V in debug mode...
[!] Your app isn't using AndroidX.
    To avoid potential build failures, you can quickly migrate your app by following the steps on

```
Compiler message:
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/graphql_flutter-2.1.0/lib/src/widgets/cache_provider.dart:64:30: Error: Getter not found: 'suspending'.
      case AppLifecycleState.suspending:
                             ^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Owner\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Owner\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        16.8s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

The package i am using is graphql_flutter v2.0.1 and i am on stable flutter channel v1.12.13+hotfix.7

Comment: Its helpful if you post code and error messages directly instead of linking to pictures on other services. We never know if your question will out-live the image hosting service :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In `pubspec.yaml` , use `any` for `graphql_flutter`

```
graphql_flutter: any
http: any
```

some tutorial code needed to modified for `graphql_flutter 3.0` 
such as change `result.hasError` to `result.hasException`

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart";

class GraphQLConfiguration {
  static HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
    uri: "https://examplegraphql.herokuapp.com/graphql",
  );

  ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
    GraphQLClient(
      link: httpLink,
      cache: OptimisticCache(dataIdFromObject: typenameDataIdFromObject),
    ),
  );

  GraphQLClient clientToQuery() {
    return GraphQLClient(
      cache: OptimisticCache(dataIdFromObject: typenameDataIdFromObject),
      link: httpLink,
    );
  }
}

GraphQLConfiguration graphQLConfiguration = GraphQLConfiguration();

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    GraphQLProvider(
      client: graphQLConfiguration.client,
      child: CacheProvider(child: MyApp()),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Example',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Principal(),
    );
  }
}

class Person {
  Person(this.id, this.name, this.lastName, this.age);

  final String id;

  final String name;

  final String lastName;

  final int age;

  getId() => this.id;

  getName() => this.name;

  getLastName() => this.lastName;

  getAge() => this.age;
}

class QueryMutation {
  String addPerson(String id, String name, String lastName, int age) {
    return """

mutation{

addPerson(id: "$id", name: "$name", lastName: "$lastName", age: $age){

id

name

lastName

age

}

}

""";
  }

  String getAll() {
    return """

{

persons{

id

name

lastName

age

}

}

""";
  }

  String deletePerson(id) {
    return """

mutation{

deletePerson(id: "$id"){

id

}

}

""";
  }

  String editPerson(String id, String name, String lastName, int age) {
    return """

mutation{

editPerson(id: "$id", name: "$name", lastName: "$lastName", age: $age){

name

lastName

}

}

""";
  }
}

class AlertDialogWindow extends StatefulWidget {
  final Person person;

  final bool isAdd;

  AlertDialogWindow({Key key, this.person, this.isAdd}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _AlertDialogWindow(this.person, this.isAdd);
}

class _AlertDialogWindow extends State<AlertDialogWindow> {
  TextEditingController txtId = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController txtName = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController txtLastName = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController txtAge = TextEditingController();

  GraphQLConfiguration graphQLConfiguration = GraphQLConfiguration();

  QueryMutation addMutation = QueryMutation();

  final Person person;

  final bool isAdd;

  _AlertDialogWindow(this.person, this.isAdd);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (!this.isAdd) {
      txtId.text = person.getId();

      txtName.text = person.getName();

      txtLastName.text = person.getLastName();

      txtAge.text = person.getAge().toString();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build

    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(this.isAdd ? "Add" : "Edit or Delete"),
      content: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: TextField(
                    maxLength: 5,
                    controller: txtId,
                    enabled: this.isAdd,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                      labelText: "ID",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    maxLength: 40,
                    controller: txtName,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.text_format),
                      labelText: "Name",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 160.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    maxLength: 40,
                    controller: txtLastName,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.text_rotate_vertical),
                      labelText: "Last name",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 240.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    maxLength: 2,
                    controller: txtAge,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Age", icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today)),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text("Close"),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
        !this.isAdd
            ? FlatButton(
                child: Text("Delete"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  GraphQLClient _client = graphQLConfiguration.clientToQuery();

                  QueryResult result = await _client.mutate(
                    MutationOptions(
                      document: addMutation.deletePerson(txtId.text),
                    ),
                  );

                  if (!result.hasException) Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            : null,
        FlatButton(
          child: Text(this.isAdd ? "Add" : "Edit"),
          onPressed: () async {
            if (txtId.text.isNotEmpty &&
                txtName.text.isNotEmpty &&
                txtLastName.text.isNotEmpty &&
                txtAge.text.isNotEmpty) {
              if (this.isAdd) {
                GraphQLClient _client = graphQLConfiguration.clientToQuery();

                QueryResult result = await _client.mutate(
                  MutationOptions(
                    document: addMutation.addPerson(
                      txtId.text,
                      txtName.text,
                      txtLastName.text,
                      int.parse(txtAge.text),
                    ),
                  ),
                );

                if (!result.hasException) {
                  txtId.clear();

                  txtName.clear();

                  txtLastName.clear();

                  txtAge.clear();

                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }
              } else {
                GraphQLClient _client = graphQLConfiguration.clientToQuery();

                QueryResult result = await _client.mutate(
                  MutationOptions(
                    document: addMutation.editPerson(
                      txtId.text,
                      txtName.text,
                      txtLastName.text,
                      int.parse(txtAge.text),
                    ),
                  ),
                );

                if (!result.hasException) {
                  txtId.clear();

                  txtName.clear();

                  txtLastName.clear();

                  txtAge.clear();

                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                }
              }
            }
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Principal extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Principal();
}

class _Principal extends State<Principal> {
  List<Person> listPerson = List<Person>();

  GraphQLConfiguration graphQLConfiguration = GraphQLConfiguration();

  void fillList() async {
    QueryMutation queryMutation = QueryMutation();

    GraphQLClient _client = graphQLConfiguration.clientToQuery();

    QueryResult result = await _client.query(
      QueryOptions(
        document: queryMutation.getAll(),
      ),
    );

    if (!result.hasException) {
      for (var i = 0; i < result.data["persons"].length; i++) {
        setState(() {
          listPerson.add(
            Person(
              result.data["persons"][i]["id"],
              result.data["persons"][i]["name"],
              result.data["persons"][i]["lastName"],
              result.data["persons"][i]["age"],
            ),
          );
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    fillList();
  }

  void _addPerson(context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        AlertDialogWindow alertDialogWindow =
            new AlertDialogWindow(isAdd: true);

        return alertDialogWindow;
      },
    ).whenComplete(() {
      listPerson.clear();

      fillList();
    });
  }

  void _editDeletePerson(context, Person person) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        AlertDialogWindow alertDialogWindow =
            new AlertDialogWindow(isAdd: false, person: person);

        return alertDialogWindow;
      },
    ).whenComplete(() {
      listPerson.clear();

      fillList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Example"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
            onPressed: () => _addPerson(context),
            tooltip: "Insert new person",
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Text(
              "Person",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: listPerson.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  selected: listPerson == null ? false : true,
                  title: Text(
                    "${listPerson[index].getName()}",
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    _editDeletePerson(context, listPerson[index]);
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks so much. I was trying to integrate it into another app and it took me all day for it to work. but finally i was able to do it by adding   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); in the main method. I don't know why it worked and i don't know its side effect. If anyone knows i would appreciate it. Thanks anyways

Comment: If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before runApp() has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() firs